# AndroidStudio | error when create new project

Tags: android, android-studio

When i create new project in android studio, gradle shows these three errors

[image]

I have installed jdk1.8 and have changed the 'Path' but this error persists.

Comment: Click on install repository and sync product. That should solve your 2nd error. With regards to your first, make sure that the project is actually referencing v1.8 of the jdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Provide compile option in `build.gradle`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

2) Press 'install repository' and install necessary packages.

3) Show your `build.gradle` for the app module?

Comment: TNX, first error solve but when i click on Install Repository show error "All package are not available for download! ..."

Comment: @sadegh show the whole build.gradle file for the whole project and for the app module.

Answer (score 1):

change the code in build.gradle file from app folder

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

after that sync gradle again. I hope this will help you. All the best